# NLTK created string regex not working

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I'm trying to do a regex match for a string I got from NLTK.  I have a stock class with a method that gets 10k's from edgar and downloads them to a string using NLTK as such.

```
def get_raw_10ks(self):
                for file in self.files_10k:
                        data = self.__get_data_from_url(file)
                        raw = nltk.clean_html(data)
                        self.raw_10ks.append(raw)
```

Then, in my program itself, I have

```
stock.get_raw_10ks()
matchObj = re.match("Indicates", stock.raw_10ks[0])
print matchObj.group()
```

I get the error

```
print matchObj.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

However, when I check the type of `stock.raw_10ks[0]`, it is a string, and when I print it out, one of the last lines is "Indicates management compensatory plan", so I'm not sure what's wrong.  I checked that re and nltk are imported correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.match()` matches the pattern at the beginning of the input string. You should use `re.search()` instead.

```
# match()
>>> re.match('Indicates', 'Indicates management compensatory')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002CC8100>
>>> re.match('Indicates', 'This Indicates management compensatory')

# search()
>>> re.search('Indicates', 'This Indicates management compensatory')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002CC8168>
```

See [`search() vs match()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

---

To make the program robust check the return value of the call:

```
matchObj = re.search("Indicates", stock.raw_10ks[0])
if matchObj is not None: # OR  if matchObj:
    print matchObj.group()
else:
    print 'No match found.'
```

---

BTW, if you want to check `Indicates` is in the string, using [`in` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) is more preferable:

```
>>> 'Indicates' in 'This Indicates management compensatory'
True
>>> 'Indicates' in 'This management compensatory'
False
```

Comment: I know you're going for completeness by adding the check for ``is not None``, but for propriety's sake, you could at least give me credit for demonstrating it first.

Comment: @AaronHall, Both `if matchObj is not None` and `if matchObj` are okay. I was in the middle of editing.